# passport always return 401 even it already logged in, both localStrategy and googleStrategy

Tags: node.js, passport.js, mean-stack

I'm noob in NodeJS and I have some problem with Passport Authenticate.

First of all, I have to tell that I was search and retry for authenticate solution on both google and stackoverflow about 2 weeks and I can't solve this, so thank you for every reply.

My app based on MEAN stack build with Express.js and Passport for authorize.
And we need to authorize on some section, and we allowed Local login and Google Login.

After I tried so far, I solve problem and problem about authorize and last thing I can't figure out is

**Every Authorize success always return 401 on both LocalStrategy and GoogleStrategy**

And this is my code.

**App**

```
app.use(require('morgan')('dev')); //combined
app.use(require('cookie-parser')());
app.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(require('body-parser').json());
app.use(require('method-override')('_method'));
app.use(require('express-session')({ secret: config.sessionKey, resave: false, saveUninitialized: false, cookie: { secure: true } }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use('/', require('./app/config/route'));
```

**Passport**

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
var config = require('./config');
var User = require('../models/user');


passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
            User.findOne({'email':  email}, function(err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    mgHooks.sendError(err);
                    return done(err);
                }
                if (user) {
                    return done(null, {status: config.statusText.NotOk, message: config.talkback.usedEmail});
                } else {
                    var newUser = new User();
                    newUser.email = email;
                    newUser.name = req.body.name;
                    newUser.secret = md5(email);
                    newUser.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
                    newUser.save(function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            mgHooks.sendError(err)
                            throw err;
                        }
                        return done(null, {
                            status: config.statusText.Ok,
                            message: config.talkback.signupSuccess,
                            user: newUser.id
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    })
);

passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
        User.findOne({'email': email}, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                mgHooks.sendError(err);
                return done(err);
            }
            if (!user){
                return done(null, {status: config.statusText.NotOk, message: config.talkback.invalidLogin});
            }
            if (!user.validPassword(password)){
                return done(null, {status: config.statusText.NotOk, message: config.talkback.invalidLogin});
            }
            //Valid, then login
            var now = new Date();
            user.lastVisited = now;
            user.save();
            return done(null, {
                status: config.statusText.Ok,
                message: config.talkback.signupSuccess,
                user: user.id
            });
        });

    }));

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: config.google.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: config.google.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: config.google.CALLBACK_URL
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        User.findOrCreate({provider: profile.provider, uid: profile.id}, function (err, user) {
            var updateUser = {
                name: profile.displayName,
                photo: profile.photos[0].value ,
                email: profile.emails[0].value,
                _raw: profile._raw
            };
            User.findOneAndUpdate({provider: profile.provider, uid: profile.id}, updateUser, function(err, doc){
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    mgHooks.sendError(err);
                }
                return done(err, user);
            });
        });
    }
));
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user);
});
```

**Route**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');

//Authorize function
var auth = function(req, res, next){
    if (!req.isAuthenticated())
        res.send(401);
    else
        next();
};

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});

router.use('/api/auth', auth, require('../controllers/api'));

router.get('/auth/loggedin', function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.isAuthenticated() ? req.user : 'unauthorized');
});

router.post('/auth/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup'), function(req, res){
    res.send(req.user);
});

router.post('/auth/login', passport.authenticate('local-login'), function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.user);
});
router.post('/auth/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logOut();
    res.send(200);
});
router.get('/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read'] })
    );
router.get('/auth/google/callback', 
    passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/#!/login' }),
    function(req, res) {
        // Successful authentication, redirect home.
        res.redirect('/#!/profile');
    });
```

At first I think it because of order of Middleware, but I was try with every tutorial I found and it's not work.

Please help me figured out this. **Thanks a lot!!**

Answer (score 0):

Update, I just found an example that write Session-persisted message middleware, and it works now!

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    var err = req.session.error,
    msg = req.session.notice,
    success = req.session.success;

    delete req.session.error;
    delete req.session.success;
    delete req.session.notice;

    if (err) res.locals.error = err;
    if (msg) res.locals.notice = msg;
    if (success) res.locals.success = success;

    next();
});
```